# wildcard in Makefile (what does $(1) mean?)

Tags: makefile, wildcard

In the following line,

```
selected = $(firstword $(foreach R,$(REPS),$(wildcard $(R)/$(1))))
```

what does $(1) mean?

I tried to see the value of $(1) by

```
$(info "dollar one is " $(1))
```

And it does not print anything. Does it mean it is some param. passed from somewhere and it is set NULL or is it a special variable used in wildcard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This `selected` is an expression meant to be used by [the `call` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function). Like this:

```
$(call selected,foo)
```

Make will evaluate the expand the expression, assigning "foo" to `$(1)`.

In this case it looks as if it might be meant for use with wildcards, like this:

```
SRCS := $(call selected,*.cc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure about how `$(1)` is being used in your make file but `$(1)` is the first argument passed in the terminal, say if you type `make target` then `target` will be assigned to `$(1)`.